# Set up and Integral

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bag of sand is being hit by a stick every second. After every hit 5% of the current amount of sand escapes from the bag. Assuming the bag is full, how many hits would it take it take before the bag is empty?

Comment: Thinking this is less of a calculus problem and more of an algebra problem

Comment: The question is very ambiguous, and has produced a variety of answers. Due to that, I ask the following question: Are the grains of sand themselves breakable?

Answer (score 1):

This is akin to Zeno's paradox; the bag will never empty.

Answer (score 1):

It will take forever, because each successive blow with the stick leaves us with $95 \% $ of what you had before. Eventually, you will end up with subatomic particles.

Keep whacking.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $x_n=0.95x_{N-1}=0.95^nx_0$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$  5 \%A=A/20$$

$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac {a_n}{20}=\frac{19}{20}a_n $$

it is a geometric sequence with
$$a_n=(19/20)^na_0$$

if $a_0$ is the number of grains of sand in the full bag, it will be empty if $a_n <1$.